# Table rows count from multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html-table, rows

In Javascript, I have a table that contains multiple rows (100 rows).  In my UI, I can show only 20 rows per page.  So, these rows are displayed in 5 pages.

When I am trying to get the row count of the table using tbl.rows.length, it is giving me only 20 not 100.

In this scenario, which function can I use to get the total count of the rows?

Comment: javascript does not have tables.. what plugin do you use ? or are you talking about html table accessed with javascript ?

Comment: Are you using any sort of jquery table API's or something of the sort? Or using regular HTML tables?

Comment: just HTML tables .. in our company they are not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this with javascript alone, unless you have something like `Showing 1-20 of <span id="num_rows">100</span>`, then you can grab the content of that span.

Using AJAX to query the server seems like overkill.

One way or another, you should probably just insert the total rows value into your html somewhere, and just read the value with javascript. You could even set an attribute like `data-total_rows="100"` to the table if you desire - there are plenty of options.

Whatever you choose using this method, the value would have to be updated as well if you are dynamically adding/removing rows.